# Swift, ClLocationManager slow to fire didEnterRegion

Tags: swift, swiftui, cllocationmanager

I am trying to implement directions with clLocationManager in a project.
Everything is working ok, but the didEnterrRegion function is very slow to fire.
When testing, I enter the region but only 2-3 minutes after exiting the region I get the callback. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to improve this?
This is the locationManager:

```
    private lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
            locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
            handleAuthorizationStatus(locationManager: locationManager)
            
        } else {
            //TODO: Handle error
        }
        return locationManager
    }()
```

This is which regions I am tracking, here I am also drawing each region to easier see when I enter specific region:

```
    private func getRouteSteps(_ mapView: MKMapView, route: MKRoute) {
        for monitoredRegion in locationManager.monitoredRegions {
            locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: monitoredRegion)
        }
        
        let steps = route.steps
        self.steps = steps
        
        for i in 0..<steps.count {
            let step = steps[i]
            let region = CLCircularRegion(center: step.polyline.coordinate, radius: 30, identifier: "\(i)")
            let circle = MKCircle(center: region.center, radius: region.radius)
            mapView.addOverlay(circle)
            locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
        }
        
        stepCounter += 1
        let initialMessage = "Om \(Int(steps[stepCounter].distance)) meter \(steps[stepCounter].instructions.lowercased())"
        directionMessage = initialMessage
    }
```

This is the locationManager-function:

```
extension MapViewModel: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        //        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        if directionsViewState != .isShowingRoute {
            if let location = locations.last {
                self.didUpdateRegion = "Updated region with accuracy: \(location.horizontalAccuracy)"
                let center = location.coordinate
                setNewRegionForMapView(center: center)
                isCenteringUserLocation = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        handleAuthorizationStatus(locationManager: locationManager)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        self.didEnterregion = "Entered region: \(region.identifier)"
        stepCounter += 1
        if stepCounter < steps.count {
            let message = "Om \(Int(steps[stepCounter].distance)) meter \(steps[stepCounter].instructions.lowercased())"
            directionMessage = message
            let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: message)
            speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterance)
        } else {
            directionMessage = "You have arrived at your destination!"
            stepCounter = 0
            let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: directionMessage)
            speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterance)
            for monitoredRegion in locationManager.monitoredRegions {
                locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: monitoredRegion)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am also calling locationManager.startUpdatingLocations in the init-method.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you are using `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`.

So, I have some suggestions for you:

- [METHOD 1] Apply background location updating:
  [Enable background mode to your target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQarg.png)

  Then add these lines of code:

  ```
  locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
  locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
  ```

  The line `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true` will allow your app to run in the background to receive new location event (ex: lock screen, use another app,...).

  And, `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false` will tell the system to not pause location updating, system can pause background location updating to save battery.

  Call your `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` to start listening for new location change.
- Next [METHOD 2], if above method doesn't work, you can switch to use `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()`. Its description is `Requests the user’s permission to use location services regardless of whether the app is in use.` System can wake your app to run in background to handle new location events. Remember to add the permission description for `requestAlwaysAuthorization` in `Info.plist` file.
- Next [METHOD 3], try to increase your `CLCircularRegion's radius` to higher value, ex: 50 meters. Or you can try to increase the `distanceFilter` to 2 meters, `distanceFilter = none` isn't a best option.
- Finally [METHOD 4], Make your customized region monitoring logic by **calculating distance from user's location to region's center** whenever we get a new location event, use this one `func distance(from location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationDistance`. If distance is <= your region's radius, that means user already crossed the boundary.

Hope that you can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. While testing all of this I am setting a text on the screen every time the location updates and the same for when I enter a monitored region. I get updates frequently so that doesn't seem to be an issue. I also tried to set the region radius to various values between 1-50 and all gave similar result. I appreciate the suggestion anyway! I will keep tring.

Comment: @OlleHammar 
Hope you solved your issue.

For [METHOD 4], you will need to modify your logic in:
`func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`


And, skip this function because it is slow updating.
`func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion)`